# ARKit add snap Picture but it causes rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, arkit

I create a project of AR app, then add on one tap gesture in view. But the picture is rotation. I found the  `self.sceneView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform` causes the rotation, how to solve this?

[image]

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    SCNPlane * plane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:self.sceneView.bounds.size.width / 6000 height:self.sceneView.bounds.size.height / 6000];
    UIImage * image = self.sceneView.snapshot;
    plane.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = image;

    SCNNode * node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:plane];
    [self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];

    simd_float4x4 translation = matrix_identity_float4x4;
    translation.columns[3][2] = -0.3;

    translation = matrix_multiply(self.sceneView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform,translation);
    node.simdTransform = translation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I has not fond why  camera transform has rotaion,but I multiply one  tranform to fix it ,and it work well.

```
SCNMatrix4 stranslation =  SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4Identity, 0, 0, -0.3);
    stranslation = SCNMatrix4Rotate(stranslation, M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1);
    simd_float4x4 translation = SCNMatrix4ToMat4(stranslation);

    translation = matrix_multiply(scameraTranstion,translation);
```